# Transfering a mongodb database from localhost

Tags: mongodb, data-transfer

i want to copy my collection in localhost computer to other computer i tried mongodumb but it shows

mongodump --db mydb --collection user5 --out user5.json;

2017-11-16T13:31:55.938+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:12

can anyone help

Comment: Usually it's `mongoimport` that people do this with. But it's the same reason and even added to the [official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) because apparently enough of you still do it: *"Run mongodump from the system command line, not the mongo shell."*

Comment: Thanks for the reply @NeilLunn i will try mongoimport

Comment: Umm. That's not the point. The point is you are trying to do the "inside the mongo shell" and you are not meant to do that. Go stick the manual page into a language translator and read it.

Comment: yeah i got it no shell :)